# Show child window before InitializeComponent

Tags: silverlight, childwindow

I have Silverlight application i want to show login window before main page InitializeComponent();

this method does not works:

```
public MainPage()
        {
            Login log = new Login();
            log.Show();
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
public MainPage()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
        }

 private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            Login log = new Login();
            log.Show();
        }
```

Comment: I tried to do the same but when i login succesfully it still do not show anything even i done in my ifcondition :  if (txtUsrname.Text == "Username" && txtPassword.Password == "Password")
            {
                this.DialogResult = true;                               
                Visibility = Visibility.Visible;               
            }