# How to popup login form at start up to take password (it do not popup in constructor of MainPage)

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, passwords, childwindow

I am working in silverlight and i have created a childwindow in which i have user name and passwrord.

```
private void OKButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (txtUsrname.Text == "Username" && txtPassword.Password == "Password") 
    {
        this.DialogResult = true; 
    } 
    else 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Incorrect username and/orpassword","Error",MessageBoxButton.OK);
    }
}

private void CancelButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{
    this.DialogResult = false;
}
```

And after i have my mainpage which contains the whole project GUI.Like this: (Herei also try to opopp a ChildWindow but it don't do so but when i put a MessageBox.Show("Hello"); then it is popuped)

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        loginChildWindow obj = new loginChildWindow();
        obj.Show();   //It do not pop up actually
         MessageBox.Show("hello");  //whereas thsi messagebox popups
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

So to set the login ChildWindow at startup time for my project i think i should do `InitializeComponent();` only if my password and userName are matched. so this InitializeComponent(); must be called inside the

```
if (txtUsrname.Text == "Username" && txtPassword.Password == "Password") 
 {
  InitializeComponent();
 }
```

But when i do this it will give error (its obvious that i cannot do that in constructor):

```
 public partial MainPage : UserControl
 {
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            private void OKButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                if (txtUsrname.Text == "Username" && txtPassword.Password == "Password") 
                {
                    this.DialogResult = true;
                    InitializeComponent();
                } 
                else 
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Incorrect username and/orpassword","Error",MessageBoxButton.OK);
                }
            }
        private void CancelButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
        {
            this.DialogResult = false;
        }    
    }
```

But how to solve it is my question ?

**EDIT AFTER User1 comments:**
the two classes are:

```
 public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;

        }

       private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            loginChildWindow log = new loginChildWindow();

            log.Show();
        }

    }
```

and

```
 public partial class loginChildWindow : ChildWindow
    {
        public loginChildWindow()
        {            
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtUsrname.Text == "Username" && txtPassword.Password == "Password")
            {
                MainPage obj = new MainPage();
                obj.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                obj.InitializeComponent();
               this.DialogResult = true;            
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Incorrect username and/orpassword", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK);
            }
        }
        private void CancelButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.DialogResult = false;
        }

        private void Login_Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show child window before InitializeComponent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8526230/show-child-window-before-initializecomponent)

Comment: @user1 thanks for the link .i tried the given link but the problem is when i enter the correct password it still do not show me GUI even i login succesfully it still do not show anything . see i have   set visiblity visible in my if-condition : if (txtUsrname.Text == "Username" && txtPassword.Password == "Password") { this.DialogResult = true; Visibility = Visibility.Visible; }

Comment: @user1 I also tried this(but still do not show any UI elements on  entering Correct Login):        if (txtUsrname.Text == "Username" && txtPassword.Password == "Password")
            {
                this.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
               this.DialogResult = true;
               InitializeComponent();               
            }

Comment: you are not listening to anything I am saying.. InitializeComponent() should be the first thing you do on main page. To not show anything before password is confirmed use Visibility.Collapsed on the mainpage and change to Visibility.Visible when confirmed.

Comment: But the code to confirmation password (that If CONDITION) is written in LoginPage.xaml.cs  class. whereas we setthe visiblity to collapsed in MainPage.xaml.cs classs.So when  i tried to set the visiblity in LoginPage.xaml.cs class on correclty entered Login informations (here : if (txtUsrname.Text == "Username" && txtPassword.Password == "Password") { this.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; this.DialogResult = true; InitializeComponent(); } ) IT STILL DO NOT SHOW ANY UI ELEMENTS.

Comment: @user1 please see the edit for code.

Comment: I mean the problem would be How to know in MainPage.xaml.cs class that if password entered in loginChildWindow.cs class is correct or not so that i can set the Visiblity to visible in MainPage.xaml.cs class ?

Comment: see my edit to your question

Comment: where is your edit ? it was 18 hours ago ? :P

Comment: Yes ia saw it. Could you please write it in answer below so that i mark it as answer ?

Comment: But still there is problem . What if the user pressed Cancel ?

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();    
            LoginWindow loginWnd=new LoginWindow();
            loginWnd.Closed+= new EventHandler(loginWnd_Closed);
            loginWnd.Show();          
        }
        void loginWnd_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoginWindow lw = (LoginWindow)sender;
            if (lw.DialogResult == true && lw.nameBox.Text != string.Empty)
            {
                this.textBlock1.Text = "Hello " + lw.nameBox.Text;
            }
            else if (lw.DialogResult == false)
            {
                this.textBlock1.Text = "Login canceled.";
            }
        }
```

where LoginWindow is:

```
      public LoginWindow()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
      }
      private void OKButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
      {
          this.DialogResult = true;
      }
      private void CancelButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
      {
          this.DialogResult = false;
      }

      private void LoginWindow_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
      {
          if (this.DialogResult == true && (this.nameBox.Text == string.Empty || this.passwordBox.Password == string.Empty))
          {
            e.Cancel = true;             
           ChildWindow cw = new ChildWindow();
            cw.Content = "Please Enter your name and password or click Cancel.";
            cw.Show();
          }

      }
```

Please See the link below for more information

[how-to-work-with-LoginWindows](http://www.codekhan.com/2011/05/silverlight-controls-how-to-work-with.html)

Comment: sorry .. Why you have InitializeComponent() before and please explain your logic. why you simply do "public LoginWindow;" . why not LoginWindow lm = new LoginWindow(); and then lw.show(); ?

Comment: You must make sure that the MainPage is the parent window of LoginWindow. You can check this by `var parent = LoginWindow.Parent;`

Comment: How if i try to do it in App.xaml.cs ?

Comment: I t will still not work.. First you intialise the the UI (whiwh are already contained in PROJECT MainPage and after you popup login).

Comment: yes, you should initialise the main page and then pop up a child window over the top of it.. You may also hide the mainpage layout root by setting its visibility to `Visibility.Collapsed` until the user logs in and then you may change it to `Visibility.Visible`

Comment: could you please write how i will manage the popup childwindow and MainPage with code (as i have written in question to explain my question for you). So that i understand and wil mark as answer if your approach works.

Comment: See edit for more information. Hopefully the link should help you understand

Comment: why there is a button click even on MainPage() class ? (Button_Click) I do not intend to have any button in my MainPage class.

Comment: Look at the link. In the link the button click is used for a sign in button. You could move this method into the constructor of main page

Comment: I saw there. as  i understand there the MainPage consists of a Button and when we clikc on that button will pop up child window but i want as i run my project will directly pop up the childwindow if the Username and pasword are correct then it will show the UI elements i created in my project.

Comment: as I explained you could move the method to the constructor. See edit

Comment: I do not know why you still do not try to understand me. I explained you that i want to see nothing before Login page and once if i enter Login page then it must direct me to UI display .My launch to project must direct me to display loginpage. So why YOU HAVE textBlock1 in mainpage.xaml.cs ?Thiis code will have a textblock and a button at starting

Comment: AND THIS CODE WILL NEVER POPUP at start up NEVER.........Or if you still persist on your statments thn p^lease prove it by showing output.